# R sf polygons not (all) closed

Tags: r, coordinates, sf

Sometimes when trying to construct an sf object from an sfc object I get the following error:

*“Error in MtrxSet(x, dim, type = "POLYGON", needClosed = TRUE) :polygons not (all) closed”.*

I am sure that my polygons are closed and I strongly assume that the floating error problematic causes this error. I thought a solution might be to round all coordinates of the sfc object to 1m (assuming that I am using a cartesian coordinate system). I have, however, not succeeded. Any thoughts?

```
library(sf)
p1 <- rbind(c(1000.001,1000.002), c(1000.2345,2000.23452), c(2000.23345,2000.2342), c(1000.001,1000.002))
p2 <- rbind(c(500.234,500.3234), c(500.234,100.235), c(1000.00001,1000.234), c(500.234,500.3234))
pol <-st_polygon(list(p1, p1))
pol_sfc= st_sfc(pol)
pol_sf <- st_sf(pol_sfc)
st_coordinates(pol_sf)
```

Comment: Your example works for me.

Comment: @dbaston yes, the example works but the coordinates printed in st_coordinates(pol_sf) are not rounded. I want them to be an integer value.

Comment: Rounding might not fix your problems. You might end up rounding your polygons to different integer metre coordinates. Better to hunt down the problem polygons and close them properly.

Comment: @Spacedman I am aware that this will not fix the problem in all cases...

Comment: What is it you *really* want to do? Is it a) round coordinates in the *hope* it will fix your non-closed polygons error, or b) fix the non-closed polygons error by any means necessary?

Comment: @Spacedman if you know an automated way to close all non-closed polygons by any means (e.g. by replacing the last coordinate pair with first coordinate pair so that the first and last coordinate pair match) I am also very happy with the solution.